# User to Login with either Azure AD and database auth using Laravel

Tags: laravel, azure-active-directory

I started using Laravel about 6 months ago. I am using Laravel-5.8 for my web application. The application is multiple company. Some of the users have their details in AZURE AD while others have theirs in the database. Already I have done the database authentication, where users can login based on the database details.

How do I make users login with Azure AD? I have never done this before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not from Laravel backround but I think general idea is to register an application in Azure AD, where you will specify the redirect/reply URL. The App registration will provide you with App client id and secret that you will further use to implement OAuth 2.0.